# wordpress custom query - orderby title will not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am having a problem getting a custom query to alphabetize. It keeps defaulting to displaying in the order of the date it was posted. Below is my php function.

```
function json_info2() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    // get values for all three drop-down menus
    $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
    $industry = $_REQUEST['services'];
    $state = $_REQUEST['state']; 


    // array of values for each of the three drop-downs
    $statusAll = array('complete','incomplete');
    $industryAll = array('mining','textile','machinery');
    $statesAll = array('SC','TX','WA');

    // set $statusArray dependent on whether or not "all" is selected in the dropdown menu
    if($status == "all") {
        $statusArray = array( 'key' => 'status', 'value' => $statusAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $statusArray = array( 'key' => 'status', 'value' => $status, 'compare' => '=');
    }

    if($industry == "all") {
        $industryArray = array( 'key' => 'industry', 'value' => $industryAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $industryArray = array( 'key' => 'industry', 'value' => $industry, 'compare' => '=');
    }

    if($state == "all") {
        $stateArray = array( 'key' => 'state', 'value' => $statesAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $stateArray = array( 'key' => 'state', 'value' => $state, 'compare' => '=');
    }


        $pages = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'meta_query'    => array(
                                    'relation'      => 'AND',
                                    $statusArray,
                                    $industryArray,
                                    $stateArray,    
                                        array(
                                        'key'       => '_wp_page_template',
                                        'value'     => 'template-individual-project.php',
                                        'compare'   => '='
                                    )
                                )
        );

        // query results by page template
        $my_query = new WP_Query($pages);


        if($my_query->have_posts()) : 
                while($my_query->have_posts()) : 
                    $my_query->the_post();  

                    <li>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </li>

                    <?php

            endwhile;endif;

            wp_reset_query();

         } // end of isset

                    ?>

         <?php
             die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_json_info2', 'json_info2' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_json_info2', 'json_info2' );
         ?>
```

This above function is called by the ajax function that follows:

```
function do_ajax() {
// Get values from all three dropdown menus
        var state = $('#states').val();
        var markets = $('#markets').val();
        var services = $('#services').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl, 
                data: {
                    'action' : 'json_info2',
                    'state' : state,
                    'status' : markets,
                    'services' : services
                },
                success:function(moredata) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    $('#project-list').html( moredata );
                    $('#project-list').fadeIn();
                }/*,
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    var errorMsg = "No results match your criteria";
                    $('#project-list').html(errorMsg);
                }*/
            }); // end of ajax call
        } // end of function do_ajax
```

Is there something simple that I'm missing here? I have a similar custom query on the page when it loads (although that initial load query doesn't have the select menu values as args), and they display in alphabetical order just fine. It's only after the ajax call to filter the list that they are no longer in order.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue after googling the problem for quite a while. I read that some of the people who were having this problem found that their theme was using a plugin called Post Types Order. It overrides the ability to set the orderby arg.

I looked at the plugins, and sure enough, Post Types Order was there. Everything I read said that the problem could be solved by unchecking "auto sort" in the settings for the plugin. However, I did that, and orderby still didn't work. I had to completely deactivate the plugin to get orderby title to work.